# acer aspire 5532

Tags: power

i have an acer aspire 5532 with power on problems. it doesnt turn on when the power button is pushed, it lights then thats it... i have two other 5532 laptops & when i swap the hard drive to one of them everything works fine. so it has to be a hardware problem. swapping batteries also has no affect. there is a small power board located at the bottom of the LCD display, if i replace it will it fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

No way for anyone to know if that will fix it or not, if the part is cheap give it a try. Many Acer models are prone to motherboard problems.

What you can try, disconnect AC power and remove the main battery, hold the power button down for 15 seconds, connect AC power Only and try to power up.

If this does nothing you will need to send it to a repair facility for diagnosis and repair.

**It could be the battery is dead and the AC adapter is not working properly to power the notebook or charge the battery.